# React - Transferring Data from Child to Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a react website and i'm stuck on a problem that has to do with passing data from a component, back to the App.js file.

so:
In my app.js file, i have a Router, that routes any request to path '/signin' to the  Component. What i want to do, is i want to take a boolean from the  component and store it in the app.js script, so that whenever that boolean is changed in the  Component, it also changes on the app.js script.

Any suggestions on how i can do this? Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: The component can accept a function as a prop and call that function with data from the component.  Or both components could reference the same application-wide state (context, Redux, etc.) and update it.

Comment: What router are you using? `react-router-dom`? If so, what version? Off David's second comment I've been having some fun with [Jotai](https://jotai.org/) recently which might be a nice way to solve your state management issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the changeValue function will change the value in the App component. Since value is passed as props to ChildComponent, as soon as it changes, it will change in ChildComponent as well

```js
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const changeValue = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent
        changeValue={changeValue}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const ChildComponent = ({changeValue, value}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{value}</p>
      <input
        type='text' 
        onChange={(e) => changeValue(e.target.value)}
       />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it Works really well apart from one thing:
since the useState in the App.js script is set to useState(' '), every time i exit the page that the xomponent is attached to, the value just resets to ' '. To clarify, i have the component attached to the /signin directory and when i leave that directory the App.js script re-runs, therefore resetting the value that i needed back to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Store the state at the parent level, and pass down the modifier function to the child via props or context.